# Do all matplotlib figures have to be square?

Tags: python, matplotlib

It seems the only way I can make the figure a rectangle (to save vertical space), is by skewing the image which makes all text on the screen skew also.

How can I make the height of the figure smaller, without touching the width, or the text presentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `figsize` keyword argument can be passed when creating a matplotlib figure using [`plt.figure()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure) as shown below.

The `figsize` keyword argument states the figure size in inches. You pass a 2-item tuple of the form `(width, height)`. This allows you to choose the size (and hence aspect ratio) of your figure before you plot any data. Below I have created a figure with `width=16in` and `height=4in`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: This is what I had: fig = plt.figure(figsize=(600/96, 300/96), dpi=96) but I thought the labels looked stretched. I guess it was just in my head.